# SSH CA signed keys, one accepted, one rejected

Tags: centos, ssh, openssh, sshd, authentication

I have several CentOS 9 and one CentOS 7 VM. All are configured to trust my SSH CA for Key verification. I can ssh into all of them with key A, but the CentOS 7 VM rejects Key B. I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong, both are signed by the same CA with the same principle for logging in. The details of Key A are:

```
.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub:
    Type: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com user certificate
    Public key: RSA-CERT SHA256:u75yZ/08ZApB3/Vyq0Y48gACwNHL/WrLKtDQP51ftMg
    Signing CA: RSA SHA256:L4QSnMqV0ohHA7qMlS58VBcKVlmL1FB/vaIAs7vC6zw (using rsa-sha2-512)
    Key ID: "matt"
    Serial: 1
    Valid: forever
    Principals: 
            matt
    Critical Options: (none)
    Extensions: 
            permit-X11-forwarding
            permit-agent-forwarding
            permit-port-forwarding
            permit-pty
            permit-user-rc
```

Key B:

```
.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub:
    Type: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com user certificate
    Public key: RSA-CERT SHA256:RAxiw1VaHXlE3rjagbQDt1dMs7dJWxECftlJbEW0zqg
    Signing CA: RSA SHA256:L4QSnMqV0ohHA7qMlS58VBcKVlmL1FB/vaIAs7vC6zw (using rsa-sha2-512)
    Key ID: "ans-usr"
    Serial: 2
    Valid: forever
    Principals: 
            matt
    Critical Options: (none)
    Extensions: 
            permit-X11-forwarding
            permit-agent-forwarding
            permit-port-forwarding
            permit-pty
            permit-user-rc
```

The sshd_config file on the CentOS 7 server is:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/ca.pub
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
```

The debug output for sshd on the CentOS 7 server when it rejects a login attempt is below:

```
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 349
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 349
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:39 setting PubkeyAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:40 setting TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/ca.pub
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:44 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:60 setting PasswordAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:61 setting PermitEmptyPasswords no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:64 setting KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:118 setting Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:hp3aeqNIbNsm3Go1vVcFJ4BxpME1At1S548JUxgkYnQ
debug1: key_load_private: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:lJGDucK20d0Ng5QPUGaLtyF2wKgw0LnOu8yIno/qc3s
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:sLq1CZONobN4r2GZPC5oXdRgMw33veo7sdeBu8NiFyg
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-ddd'
debug3: oom_adjust_setup
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 349
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.2.52 port 50574 on 192.168.2.10 port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: ssh_sandbox_init: preparing seccomp filter sandbox
debug2: Network child is on pid 2451
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug1: SELinux support enabled [preauth]
debug3: ssh_selinux_change_context: setting context from 'unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023' to 'unconfined_u:unconfined_r:sshd_net_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023' [preauth]
debug3: ssh_selinux_change_context: setcon unconfined_u:unconfined_r:sshd_net_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 from unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 failed with Invalid argument [preauth]
debug3: privsep user:group 74:74 [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: setting PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: attaching seccomp filter program [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ext-info-c [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 120 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 121 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 120
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 121
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 120 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 121 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 120
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 121
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: hostkey proof signature 0x55cbcccd2b70(83)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user matt service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 192.168.2.52.
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 349
debug3: auth_shadow_acctexpired: today 19015 sp_expire -1 days left -19016
debug3: account expiration disabled
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for matt [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authrole entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 80 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 80
debug3: mm_answer_authrole: role=
debug2: monitor_read: 80 used once, disabling now
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user matt service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable for RSA SHA256:RAxiw1VaHXlE3rjagbQDt1dMs7dJWxECftlJbEW0zqg [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x55cbcccd4e10
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/matt/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/matt/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x55cbcccd4e10 is not allowed
Failed publickey for matt from 192.168.2.52 port 50574 ssh2: RSA SHA256:RAxiw1VaHXlE3rjagbQDt1dMs7dJWxECftlJbEW0zqg
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg rsa-sha2-256 [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user matt service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
debug1: auth2_challenge: user=matt devs= [preauth]
debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices  [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
Connection closed by 192.168.2.52 port 50574 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 124 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 122 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 123 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 124
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 122
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 123
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 2451
```

Is there something here that should clue me into why this key is failing to authenticate? I can't seem to figure it out. The only potential issue I can think of the that the username of the holder of key B is not 'matt', but since the priciple is, and specify
`ssh matt@centos7vm` I don't see how that could be an issue given it works on every CentOS 9 VM I have without fail. Thank you for the assistance.

Update: I can also get into an Ubuntu vm with this sshd_config file, so the problem at least appears to be specific to CentOS 7.

Comment: Guess: Differences between the ssh versions in CentOS 9 vs. 7. Maybe read the man-pages for `ssh`/`sshd` on both versions, and look for differences in how they handle a CA?

Comment: I think you're onto something here. My CentOS 7 vm is the only one running OpenSSH 7, the rest are on 8. The man pages was pretty sparse in covering how they handle CA's, so I'll have to do some more digging. Thank you.